# Rails 4 : Access attributes from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have a Model Reservation with 2 columns, `user_id` and `teleporter_id`.

I want to lock the creation of a Reservation to 3 same `teleporter_id` but I don't know how to access to the attribute `teleporter_id` from the Model that I'm creation.

Here my code :

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Relations
  belongs_to :teleporter
  belongs_to :user

  # Validations
  validate :max_reservation

  def max_reservation
    if Reservation.where(:teleporter_id => self.teleporter_id).count >= 3
      errors.add(:base, t('reservation.model.error.max_reservation'))
    end
  end
end
```

I think that the problem is from `self.teleporter_id` but I don't know how access to the attribut teleporter_id from the current model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def max_reservation
  _id = self.teleporter_id
  errors.add(:base, t('reservation.model.error.max_reservation')) unless Reservation.where(teleporter_id: _id).count <= 3
end
```